# S3 Bucket Notification or CloudWatch Event Rule to call a Lambda on Object level changes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I need to start a Lambda Function when an object has been created on an S3 Bucket. I found 2 solutions to do this.

1. Using `AWS::S3::Bucket NotificationConfiguration`.
2. Using a CloudWatch `AWS::Events::Rule`.

They both seem to do exactly the same thing, which is to track specific changes and launch a Lambda Function when it happens. I could not find any information on which one should be used. I'm using `Cloud Formation Template` to provision the Lambda, the S3 Bucket and the trigger.

Which one should I use to call a Lambda on Object level changes and why?

Answer (score 2):

Use the 1st one because of

- A push model is much better than a pull model. Push means you send data when you get it instead of polling onto something for some set of interval. This is an era for push notifications all over us. You don't go to facebook to check every 5 minutes if someone has liked your picture or not OR someone has replied to your comment, etc.
- In terms of cost and efforts also, S3 event notification wins the race.
- Cloudwatch was the best option if you didn't have S3 notification but since you have it, that's the best. Plus if you have a feature in the service itself then why will you go for an alternative solution like Cloudwatch rules.

Comment: I kinda agree with you for the most part, but what makes you say that cloudwatch events aren't push based ?

Comment: @AmineZaine Let me add the missing line here - Under rules in cloudwatch, `Event Pattern` is _push_ where as `Schedule` is _poll_.